# How to copy table from a database on SERVER 1 to another database on SERVER 2 using phpMyAdmin?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, cpanel, large-data, whm

I have a database named **db_x on server X (running WHM)** and another database named **db_y on server Y**. I connected to server X via SSH made some changes to the phpmyadmin configurations to allow it to connect to db_y via phpmyadmin on server X via cPanel. Now, I want to move all the tables of the db_x on server_X to another database(db_y) which is on different server(yy.yy.yy.yy) by using phpMyAdmin from server_X.

Is there any way to do so? Please help me.

**Edit:** The table is over 3 GB, so export/import won't work.

Comment: just export the original and import it to the receiver, documentation : https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/import_export.html

Comment: Importing and exporting won't work as the table size is over 3 GB

Answer (score 2):

due to the size of your database you will not be able to succeed with phpmyadmin.

Try use the SSH.

Upload the database to the new server "old_database.sql".
Considering that the database already existis on the new server, use the command below:

```
# mysql new_database < old_database.sql
```

This command will import your sql file into the new database.

If you don't have the old_database.sql file, you can also obtain it with command in old server

```
# mysqldump mydatabase > old_database.sql
```

This command will generate an SQL file from your database.

Answer (score 0):

Ther will be an option  **export** in db_x export it and in db_y click import 
   and chose downloaded file wich was exported and click run.